# why the CSS is Losing when i put "/" in the end of url on my system

Tags: php, html, css

I am developing a web-based human-resource system with biometrics and Android Application as my Capstone Project (Thesis). I've tried this code:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="< ?php echo site_url(); ? >css/index.css">
```

...as a solution to my first problem, that when I put "`/`" to the end of the url of my system, like `localhost/mcchr/index.php/`, my CSS doesn't work but when I add this to my code, my page becomes a blank page. How can I fix that?

Comment: are you using codeigniter?

Comment: no im just using Sublime Text 2

Comment: He meant what is the framework your using. Open the developers tab see the networks. You can check if your css is loaded.

Comment: The extra `/` would suggest your in a new folder

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="< ?php echo site_url(); ? >css/index.css">
```

to

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>css/index.css">
```

Remove extra space between ? and >

Comment: i do that already but still it is a blank page